# PHP: Wrong URI with and without variable

Tags: php, html, variables

I try to modify a web application written in PHP and need some help. The Application is designed to work in the ROOT path of the Webserver. I do some changes to get it work in paths but have still one issue, and this drives me crazy right now. Hope someone of you guys can help me out...

As i mentioned the application is designed to work

```
echo '<a href="'. DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR .$variable. DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR .$variable.'">
                                <img src="'. DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR .$variable. DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR .$filename.'" />
                                </a>';
```

The application is based in /var/www/html/test/
The browser tries to get the link and image from localhost/variable/filename.jpg

So, I thought ok, lets write another variable and set there the path. So i wrote this:

```
echo '<a href="'. $path . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR .$variable. DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR .$filename.'">
                                <img src="'. $path. DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR .$variable. DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR .$filename.'" />
                                </a>';
```

Variable path is set to 'test'
The Browser tries now to get the image from localhost/test/test/variable/filename.jpg

```
localhost = Server
test = the path (window.location)
test = my $path
variable = my $variable
filename = my $filename
```

Any ideas?

Thank you!

Comment: You shouldn't use `DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR` when building URLs. It is used for building paths on the filesystem where the separator can change from backslash `\ ` on windows to forward slash `/` on *nix systems. With URLs it is always just forward slash.

Comment: Thanks for that, but this is not the fix for my issue, right?

Comment: That's why it's just a comment and not an answer.

Comment: ok, thank you! I remove the DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR and replaced it by '/'. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set `$path` to `/test` instead of just `test`. If you don't include the leading `/`, the URL is considered relative to the current path. By including it, it is relative to the domain.

You could also set it to something like `.` which would make the URL relative to the current path (which is `test`).

Comment: Oh man, that was really easy. I tried a lot but not that! Its working now! Thank you!